# Cucumber. Skip all scenarios, if one failed

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I have some tests. Like

```
@skip_if_failed
Scenario: Test
```

...

```
Scenario: Test2
```

...

```
Scenario: Test3
```

I write in hooks code like:

```
After('@skip_if_failed') do |scenario|
 if scenario.failed?
  scenario.all each do |scenario|
    scenario.fail
  end
    end
 end
```

I would like, if scenarios(@skip_if_failed) failed. I skip all other scenarios.I use Cucumber 2.0.2 and Ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 3):

I use an env variable called FAIL_QUICK and set to true if I want to stop on the first failure.

```
After do |scenario|
  Cucumber.wants_to_quit = true if scenario.failed? && ENV['FAIL_QUICK']
end
```

then I call as follows:

```
FAIL_QUICK=true cucumber
```

Comment: @dmcnulla
Thank you so much. Please tell me is it possible to do to skip the tests only within a single feature? To other features again been tested by Tag? -

Comment: Tags are open so you can have 20 different tags, or more. That wouldn't be so beneficial to most people. You can test that one tag with this strategy. A failure will stop all others by that tag. You can run a series of cukes by different tags, one at a a time.